# How does iPhoto synchronize photos between my macbook pro and my wife's one?

Tags: photos.app

When my wife imports photos on her mac book pro, they are quickly synchronized in my own iPhoto.

We share the same apple id, but I do not remember having set anything specific to have this (excellent) behavior. How does it work ? (that means : what is the setting to obtain this behavior ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible answers here:

1. You are both sharing the same iCloud/.me/.mac account. Look in System Preferences > iCloud > [Account Details] on both systems to compare.
2. That your wife has shared a Photo Stream with you. Run iPhoto and look at the left hand sidebar in the section named 'Shared'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We effectively share the same appleId. So, in that case, every photo is synced with full size... Interesting.